# marshmallow limit depth of serialization

Tags: python, serialization, marshmallow

Is there a way to limit how deep the marshmallow serialization will go when `schema.dump()` is called?

For example, consider I have classes nested 4 layers deep, but I only want the serialization to go down to the 3rd layer?